# HTTPサーバ機能で複数ユーザを作り、それぞれのprogramだけを表示したい

Tags: python, supervisord

supervisorを使っておりますが、
[inet_http_server]の項目にて、
usernameとpasswordがありますが、
それを複数にし、
ログインしたユーザごとに、表示したいprogramを分けたいと思っています。
可能でしょうか？
何卒、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: program A と program B を supervisord から起動したうえで、WebインターフェイスにユーザーAとしてログインしたら program A のみが、ユーザーBとしてログインしたら program B のみが表示される、といったことでしょうか。

Comment: unaristさん

はい、そのとおりです。
ログインした人のprorgamだけを表示させたいです。
しかし、そもそも、複数のユーザを作る方法が不明です。

Comment: やはり無理なのでしょうか？
それとも独自でWebページを作るしかないですかね。